# Are there any good substrate dev meetups in London?

Tags: community

If I want to meet and chat with other parachain developers or devs building on parachains (with a substrate of beer and pizza), are there any good meetups in London where we could do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just announced there is a new meetup series in London dedicated to making Web3 a reality:

https://www.meetup.com/beyond-the-chain-london/

Comment: Upcoming london meetup: https://www.meetup.com/beyond-the-chain-london/events/296057354/